# Remove only text-shadow from selected text with just CSS

Tags: css

I styled some text to have a faint white text-shadow so that when it passes on a same-color background, it's style legible. The issue comes in that when I select the text, it becomes difficult to read thanks to the text-shadow being the same color as the text.

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  padding: 1.5em;
}

div + div {
  margin: 2em 0 0;
}

div p:last-child {
  margin: 0em;
}

p {
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.actual-effect ::selection {
  text-shadow: none;
}

.intended-effect p {
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="actual-effect">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Optime, inquam.</a> Istam voluptatem, inquit, Epicurus ignorat? Inde igitur, inquit, ordiendum est. Eam tum adesse, cum dolor omnis absit; Ne discipulum abducam, times. </p>

<p><i>Certe non potest.</i> <mark>Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis etiam.</mark> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Duo Reges: constructio interrete.</a> Recte dicis; Hoc loco tenere se Triarius non potuit. </p>

<p>Non igitur bene. Utram tandem linguam nescio? <b>Quis est tam dissimile homini.</b> Quae sequuntur igitur? Quod ea non occurrentia fingunt, vincunt Aristonem; Hoc ipsum elegantius poni meliusque potuit. </p>
</div>

<div class="intended-effect">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Optime, inquam.</a> Istam voluptatem, inquit, Epicurus ignorat? Inde igitur, inquit, ordiendum est. Eam tum adesse, cum dolor omnis absit; Ne discipulum abducam, times. </p>

<p><i>Certe non potest.</i> <mark>Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis etiam.</mark> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Duo Reges: constructio interrete.</a> Recte dicis; Hoc loco tenere se Triarius non potuit. </p>

<p>Non igitur bene. Utram tandem linguam nescio? <b>Quis est tam dissimile homini.</b> Quae sequuntur igitur? Quod ea non occurrentia fingunt, vincunt Aristonem; Hoc ipsum elegantius poni meliusque potuit. </p>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how other browsers render this, but currently in Firefox it accurately removes the text-shadow, but it loses all of the default stylings it would have had had I not changed it (ie. white text, blue background, inverted colors when juxtaposed against a certain backgrounds, etc).

Is there a way to modify ::selection without losing all of the default values? I'd rather not re-add all of the default styles unless that were the only option available.

Comment: what you're describing is not normal and there's probably something else we're not seeing affecting this, Could you add a working code snippet illustrating the issue ?

Comment: Edited in a snippet.

Comment: This seems like a bug, but from what i've read `::selection` is un reliable and it just doesn't work for some obscure reason, i've some examples online that use the background to hide the text-shadow but that is more of a hack and it won't work if text-shadow is too big.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue isn't avoiding that the text-shadow makes things difficult to read, it's more-so trying to avoid p::selection from losing everything else.

Sorry for previous answer .
You can set the `text-shadow` to `0 0 0`.

Example :

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 1.5em;
}

p {
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

::selection {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Optime, inquam.</a> Istam voluptatem, inquit, Epicurus ignorat? Inde igitur, inquit, ordiendum est. Eam tum adesse, cum dolor omnis absit; Ne discipulum abducam, times. </p>

<p><i>Certe non potest.</i> <mark>Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis etiam.</mark> <a href="http://loripsum.net/" target="_blank">Duo Reges: constructio interrete.</a> Recte dicis; Hoc loco tenere se Triarius non potuit. </p>

<p>Non igitur bene. Utram tandem linguam nescio? <b>Quis est tam dissimile homini.</b> Quae sequuntur igitur? Quod ea non occurrentia fingunt, vincunt Aristonem; Hoc ipsum elegantius poni meliusque potuit. </p>
```

### Previous Answer (unsatisfactory)

It's because background, change that. I'm try use `background-color: transparent`, but it's not work. So, in this code i use `background-color: #fff`.

```css
p {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
}

p::selection {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem numquam, laboriosam distinctio impedit qui explicabo corporis optio commodi officiis ratione voluptates corrupti, temporibus iusto recusandae facilis nobis obcaecati nisi quisquam iste ullam excepturi iure. Ratione, molestiae mollitia vitae, error soluta illum ex accusamus voluptatem tempora hic aut rerum! Recusandae impedit consectetur consequatur dolorum, dolore aut officiis nam tenetur aliquid repudiandae natus velit sapiente vero esse, dolor quasi illo at consequuntur aperiam explicabo iusto corporis ex fugit architecto? Placeat, unde suscipit expedita enim ab vel iste cumque quas, asperiores adipisci accusamus? Et, minus. Saepe magni quo, ipsam enim earum placeat voluptates.</p>
```

Comment: The issue isn't avoiding that the text-shadow makes things difficult to read, it's more-so trying to avoid `p::selection` from losing everything else.

Comment: I've edited the example to provide an example of both the actual ::selection effect vs what is intended. Sorry for any confusion on my part.

Comment: Hi! I've updated the post! I removed the `transparent` background, if used, it is not correct, and after removing it, seems to be the answer you want